# Difference between "dealer" and "concessionaire"

Tags: word-request, difference

In a system for control sales of vehicles, which is the appropriate word. **Dealer** or **concessionaire**? In order to refer to a place where they do sell vehicles.

What are the differences?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[**Concessionaire** is so uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dealer%2Cconcessionaire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdealer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconcessionaire%3B%2Cc0) I don't think I've ever heard anyone use the word.  Also, it usually refers to someone who operates a specific business (a *concession*) on someone else's property.  Don't use it.  The idiomatic term in US English for someone who sells cars is a [**car dealer**](https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=car_dealers&find_loc=Jersey%20City%2C%20NJ).

Comment: You're right that the term is not in use, though we do still sell things on concession. Don't pawn shops technically work that way?

Comment: @WillowRex - I think you mean *on consignment*, as Andrew said.  A *concession* is a specific type of business: "a space or privilege within certain premises for a subsidiary business or service", like the popcorn stand at a fairground.

Comment: @Willow: My search - "sell things on concession" - [did not match any book results.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=+%22sell+things+on+concession%22) Are you sure you're not thinking of [*sell things on **commission**?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=+%22sell+things+on+commission%22)

Comment: @stangdon  I'm sure it's a word used by lawyers in certain circles.  Like consignee and consignor, it's probably only used in court.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, I had to fall on my sword. I did so in my answer below. Colour me embarrassed! Thanks, I forgot I'd made a comment, too.

Comment: @Willow: Your English certainly isn't bad overall, so OP should simply take your "lapses" as further evidence that he really shouldn't bother trying to get his head around the subtleties of ***concession, commission, consignment*** until he's got a firmer grasp of basic English (the question text has several much more obvious problems than anything to do with using relatively uncommon words correctly).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am Canadian with English as a first language. I was reading concession and seeing consignment -- a pure 'senior moment'. It does speak to how easy it is to make mistakes in English, and that is why I am leaving it there, regardless of how I feel about my error!

Comment: US English here - I've never heard *concessionaire* before. Even so, I immediately would think that this person is one who runs a concession stand (like at a sports game or something)...But *even then* is that word never used. I'd just say "I'm buying something from the concession stand", and the person who works there would just be ...a "seller" I guess. We don't (as far as I know and have ever heard) use such a specific term colloquially.

Comment: In the UK a "dealership" or "dealer" usually refers to a *business* that sells new or used cars. The individual people who work there are "salesmen" or "saleswomen".

Comment: @alephzero - Yup, mostly same in the US, although the guy who owns the business is probably just called a "dealer".

Answer (score 3):

definitions from Google dictionary

> concessionaire
>
> noun the holder of a concession or grant, especially for the use of
>   land or commercial premises.

This definition is correct but doesn't help in this context.

I know now the part below is wrong! I am keeping it here because I think it's important to 'fess up to errors.

---

*If you are holding something in concession (I think this is what you are asking), then the concessionaire gets a percentage of the sale of the product or item that the seller earns. I sell used clothing (I am the owner) and earn three dollars but I must give a percentage to the concessionaire of 10%, so they earn thirty cents. The concessionaire owns the store where I can then sell my used item. On Edit: We do not use the term: concessionaire. We use owner, store manager, concession or more likely re-sale store owner. Some galleries sell art on concession.*

---

> dealer
>
> noun
>   1. a person or business that buys and sells goods. "a car dealer"
>
> (2. the player who distributes the cards at the start of a game or
>   hand.*)
>    * not useful

A dealer generally has paid for the goods and therefore is the owner of them. They then sell for a profit, that item to a customer.

Comment: This term is not common.  Depending on context this person might be called a *broker*, an *agent*, or a *franchise owner*, or various other descriptions.

Comment: We called her "the nearly new store owner".  I think I'll edit, though. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you mean selling on *consignment*.  The person who owns a store that sells things on consignment is the *consignee*, but again, this term is probably not often used except in contracts.  :)

Comment: @Andrew Darn it: YES!  So, should I delete my answer, because it is wrong!

Comment: No, it's fine.  I just added additional information in case it's useful to anyone.

Comment: @Andrew I fell on my sword because I learned something, or re-learned it at any rate. Mistakes are good learning tools, so I am letting it go... Thanks so letting me know so nicely.

Comment: I made some edits to give you an idea of what might be a better way to keep the mistaken bits in your answer. If you don't like it, click the "edited" link above my icon, and just rollback to the previous revision. You can also click "edit" on the version in the history you want to start editing from instead of rolling back and then editing.

Comment: thanks, now I understand I might adjust tomorrow, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Dealer is the word you are looking for.  Concessionaire has a very specific meaning that would only apply in very specific circumstances.  The definition "the holder of a concession or grant, especially for the use of land or commercial premises" is accurate but needs examples.  The US government "owns" Yellowstone Nation Park and operates the Park generally.  Park Service personnel staff the Entrance gates, Visitor Centers, campgrounds, and police the roads and back country.  But the Park Service grants concessions to other companies that operate the Hotels, Gas Stations, and Stores.  The company that operates the Park's Hotels is the concessionaire for the Hotels concession.  The company that operates the Park's Gas Stations is the concessionaire for the Gas Station concession.  Likewise for the Park's stores.  Similarly, the owner / operator of large sports and concert venues usually offers a concession of the "snack food" business inside the venue.  The operator of the snacks concession is the snacks concessionaire at that venue.

So, the only way a car dealer would also be a concessionaire would be in a specific situation where, for example, the owner of Yankee Stadium in New York granted a concession to operate a car dealership inside the stadium (on Stadium grounds).  The owner/operator of the concession might be a Lexus dealer during one concession contract and a BMW dealer during another contract.  Both contract holders (Both car dealers) would be considered Yankee Stadium's automobile concessionaire during the terms their contracts were in force.

Answer (score 1):

From my stint in Italy, Concessionaires are owned directly by the Car manufacturers, while dealers are independent Value-Added resellers. The earlier often carry a larger bouquet of services as a result. As observed by many, concessionaire is hardly ever used in daily English, and could be misleading if you were trying to make the distinction I just referred to. Hope this helps. Cheers!